# All Environments and Groups missing

Tags: paw-app

I opened Paw this morning and all my Environments, Groups and Paw documents are gone. Any idea where the Environments info is stored? Been using Paw for almost a year and never had this happen. No recent updates or changes. I closed the app last night to shut down and everything was there.

Not a huge deal if the info is gone but would be nice to recover if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Did you save your Paw document to a file or just used the OSX autosave?

It should be autosaved,
check in ~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Autosave Information or ~/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Data/Library/Application Support/com.luckymarmot.Paw/Rescued Documents

Environments are stored in Paw documents

Comment: Natalia I used Autosave for the most part. It is interesting that both locations you listed above are completely empty.

Comment: Are you using the Mac App Store version or the website version? Unfortunately, for unnamed documents these are the only locations Paw can autosave to due to sandboxing. We've had some issues with MAS uninstalling and re-installing silently deleting all unnamed autosaved documents and sadly this is out of our control. Best is always save your files with a name at least once.

Comment: Natalia I use the website version. Something has changed with the app in one of the latest updates. It NEVER shows what has been autosaved anymore. Sucks to have to open a PAW document each time I open the app. Postman doesnt make me do that. If I was rating now I would give it 1 star where as I have recommended Paw many times previously.

Comment: If you close Paw using CMD+Q paw will reopen all to documents that were open when paw closed.

Comment: Once you have given a file a name (used the save dialog) paw will auto save all changes to that file (you can see 'edited' in the title bar warning you the autosave has not happened yet when this goes away you are saved). But until the file has been created Paw can only save to locations within its sandbox. (OSX limitation).

Comment: The danger in saving to the sandbox dir is that some apps ('clean my mac' style of things) can try to 'clean up' these container directory and do delete our un-named autosaves. We are currently working on a paw sync feature that will allow you to syne your projects into the cloud, and merge changes.